# Can I get vaccinated for Japanese Encephalitis in India?

Tags: india, health, international-travel

I'm traveling to India, and am planning on departing in 2 weeks. The only vaccine I haven't received yet is the one for Japanese Encephalitis, which requires 2 doses that are 28 days apart.

I'll be in both urban and rural areas of India, Nepal, Thailand, and Cambodia for 8 months, so should probably get vaccinated for it. Is it possible to get the 2nd dose of the vaccine administered in one of these countries?

I'm willing to risk being there for a couple weeks before the vaccine kicks in.

Comment: I think you better consult your local doctor or other expert than trying to seek medical advice online.

Comment: You would need a doctor with local knowledge of india.

Comment: Julia, can you tell us specifically what urban areas you will be traveling to? I assure you vaccines will be available, but maybe not widely in rural areas.

Comment: @andra Drawing from credible sources. I'll be willing to ask some local doctors I know, but I gotta know the city of course.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for example [Travel Health Consultancy International Travel Health & Vaccinations Clinic](http://www.itvc.in/Vaccines.php) in Delhi. There will be other centres but you don't even specify a country so I guess Delhi is sufficient.

The risk is VERY slight ([From 1973 through 2013, 68 JE cases among travelers or expatriates from nonendemic countries were published or reported to CDC. From the time JE vaccine became available in the United States in 1993–2013, only 8 JE cases among US travelers were reported to CDC.](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/yellowbook/2014/chapter-3-infectious-diseases-related-to-travel/japanese-encephalitis)) but the consequences VERY severe (death in about 30% of cases and permanent severe disability even if survived). There is no cure.

The cost for a course seems to be anything from around $30 to $300 depending upon where (which country) and which clinic but I'd imagine India would be at the bottom end of the range and a single injection would be less than for a full course (which used to be three injections).

A decade or so ago there was a shortage of vaccine, but that no longer seems an issue, though not manufactured in India.

Comment: This link may be useful as well - http://www.itg.be/itg/Uploads/MedServ/NJAPENC%20bijlage.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In terms of simply getting the shots, yes you are able to.  I know that Thailand has a number of tropical medicine clinics where you can get all your travel inoculations (my wife and I are getting all the jabs for a visit to Africa from the gov't clinic in Chiang Mai, and I know there are a number of places in Bangkok as well).  And as India has pretty decent medical care options in the bigger cities, I imagine the same would be true there.

BUT, as Bernhard commented on your initial post, you are best advised to speak with your travel doctor at home.  There may be issues with getting one half of a series in one country and the other half in another country.